# filed showing null value when joining table

Tags: mysql, sql

below is my query

```
 select C.cName,DATE_FORMAT(CT.dTransDate,'%d-%M-%Y') as dTransDate,  
  (c.nOpBalance+IFNULL(CT.nAmount,0)) AS DrAMount,IFNULL(CTR.nAmount,0) AS 
 CrAMount,((c.nOpBalance+IFNULL(CT.nAmount,0))-IFNULL(CTR.nAmount,0)) AS     
Balance,CT.cTransRefType,CT.cRemarks,cinfo.cCompanyName,cinfo.caddress1,cinfo.cP
     honeOffice,cinfo.cMobileNo,cinfo.cEmailID,cinfo.cWebsite from  Customer    
   C  LEFT JOIN Client_Transaction CT ON CT.nClientPk = C.nCustomerPk AND 
  CT.cTransRefType='PAYMENT' AND CT.cClientType='CUSTOMER' AND CT.dTransDate    
 between '' AND ''  LEFT JOIN Client_Transaction CTR ON CTR.nClientPk = 
   C.nCustomerPk AND CTR.cTransRefType='RECEIPT' AND 
   CTR.cClientType='CUSTOMER' AND CTR.dTransDate between '2015-05-01' AND 
  '2015-05-29'   LEFT JOIN companyinfo cinfo ON cinfo.cCompanyName like
 '%Fal%' Where C.nCustomerPk = 4   Order By dTransDate
```

it's showing all value but **dTransDate** ,**cTransRefType**,**cRemarks**, showing null.

Comment: Did you have a **question**? What we see here is a badly formatted SQL statement, a terse description of some observed behavior, and a request for help. We don't see any example data, expected resultset, or any description of what this statement is supposed to be returning. What we don't see here is any actual **question** that can be meaningfully answered. [http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/](http://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Answer (score 1):

One obvious thing jumps out at us:

```
  CT.dTransDate BETWEEN '' AND '' 
                        ^^     ^^
```

Another thing that jumps out at us is that there's a semi-Cartesian join between rows from CT and rows from CTR.  If 5 rows are returned from CT for a given customer, and 5 rows are returned from CTR, that's going to produce a total of 5*5 = 25 rows. That just doesn't seem like a resultset that you'd really want returned.

Also, if more than one row is returned from `cinfo`, that's also going to cause another semi-Cartesian join. If there's two rows returned from `cinfo`, the total number or rows in the resultset will be doubled. It's valid to do that in SQL, but this is an unusual pattern.

The calculation of the `balance` is also very strange. For each row, the `nAmount` is added/subtracted from opening balance. On the next row, the same thing, on the original opening balance. There's nothing invalid SQL-wise with doing that, but the result being returned just seems bizarre. (It seems much more likely that you'd want to show a running balance, with each transaction.)

Another thing that jumps out at us is that you are ordering the rows by a string representation of a DATE, with the day as the leading portion. (As long as all the rows have date values in the same year and month, that will probably work, but it just seems bizarre that we wouldn't sort on the `DATE` value, or a canonical string representation.

---

I strongly suspect that you want to run a query that's more like this. (This doesn't do a "running balance" calculation. It does return the `'PAYMENT'` and `'RECEIPT'` rows as individual rows, without producing a semi-Cartesian result.

```
 SELECT c.cName
      , DATE_FORMAT(t.dTransDate,'%d-%M-%Y') AS dTransDate
      , C.nOpBalance
      , IF(t.cTransRefType='PAYMENT',IFNULL(t.nAmount,0),0) AS DrAMount
      , IF(t.cTransRefType='RECEIPT',IFNULL(t.nAmount,0),0) AS CrAMount
      , t.cTransRefType
      , t.cRemarks
      , ci.*
   FROM Customer c
   LEFT
   JOIN Client_Transaction t
     ON t.nClientPk      = c.nCustomerPk
    AND t.cClientType    = 'CUSTOMER'
    AND t.dTransDate    >= '2015-05-01'
    AND t.dTransDate    <= '2015-05-29'
    AND t.cTransRefType IN ('PAYMENT','RECEIPT')
  CROSS
   JOIN ( SELECT cinfo.cCompanyName
               , cinfo.caddress1
               , cinfo.cPhoneOffice
               , cinfo.cMobileNo
               , cinfo.cEmailID
               , cinfo.cWebsite
            FROM companyinfo cinfo 
           WHERE cinfo.cCompanyName LIKE '%Fal%'
           ORDER BY cinfo.cCompanyName
           LIMIT 1
        ) ci
  WHERE c.nCustomerPk = 4 
  ORDER BY t.dTransDate, t.cTransRefTpye, t.id
```